# Using my Rest Service with WSO2 API Manager

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have my REST Service  name getRates. Which accepts few inputs and gives out the loan rates. I wanted to use the API that I have with WSO2 Api Manager. I am not able to do it. I am not sure where and how to define the sample request/response code to check if my service is being hit or not. I have a URL to my Service but I want it to be used via WSO2 APi manager. Help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

Question is too generic to give an exact answer. Please follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-CreatinganAPIfromscratch) guide to create a new API from scratch and add your backend service URL as 'Production Endpoint'. If you already have set this up and want to get an idea if the message flow is working correctly, enable wire logs as follows,

- open log4j.properties file from a text editor.
  log4j.properties file is located in /repository/conf directory.
- Un-comment the following entry.

log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG

Get an idea about the wire logs from [here](http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html). Explain the steps you tried already and mention if you get any errors.

Comment: I created an API and published and subscribed to it. But it gives me error some thing like this:

Comment: I created an API and published and subscribed to it. But it gives me error some thing like this:  Curl

curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer ec87eb64dd515bc52491dd8d7953844f" "https://10.3.144.211:8243/getRates/1.0.0"
Request URL
https://10.3.144.211:8243/getRates/1.0.0

Comment: Response Body

<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
  <ams:code>900901</ams:code>
  <ams:message>Invalid Credentials</ams:message>
  <ams:description>Access failure for API: /getRates/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0. Make sure your have given the correct access token</ams:description>
</ams:fault>

Comment: Response Code

401

Comment: make sure your oauth access token is not exipred.